# Querying ExactTarget via API to retrieve subscribers who are missing an attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, fuel-sdk

I am trying to retrieve subscribers from our ExactTarget instance via the API that are missing a specific attribute (a custom value that should be inserted during the subscriber creation process but is occasionally not set correctly).

Is there a way to do this via the FuelSDK or the REST API?

I have tried to run a subscriber.search_filter command via the Python SDK but it appears that I can only run these filters based directly on the Subscriber fields themselves (CreatedDate, EmailAddress, SubscriberKey, etc) and not on the key/value pairs within the Attributes section.

What I need is something like Attributes['name of my key'] - is there a way to do this programatically without scanning through our entire subscriber database and doing the attribute check in memory?

Comment: Are you referring to searching for a missing profile attribute value of a Subscriber in the All Subscribers list, or something else? Please can you clarify?

Comment: Yes exactly. All our subscribers are meant to have a profile attribute set called "Subscriber Hash Key" which is a salted + hashed version of their emailaddress and used to allow access to our custom preferences center without having to login first. They usually have this set at creation time.

However some of our subscribers are missing this value so I am trying to design a job to go in and find and remediate these on a regular basis (hourly, etc).

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I cannot find a way to filter by Attribute name. You would assume this is possible, but I've tried different permutations and I can't seem to do this.